# undefined method `admn_no' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models **Scorecard** and **Result**

The relationship between the two is;

```
class Scorecard < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :results

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :scorecards
after_save :export_params
```

The model **Scorecard** is supposed to do a bunch of calculations and output them in a view. This is happening. It is then supposed to take a copy of the current results from the calculation and save them to **Result**. This is not happening.
Model **Scorecard** has an after_save filter that triggers the save to **Result**. It is supposed to check if the current admission number exists in the**Result** model. 
If if does, it is updated, if not, it is created. To create;

> assign_attributes

to update

> update_attributes

the implementation is as follows

```
def export_params
case admn_no
when Result.where(:admno => self.admn_no).exists?
@results.update_attributes(:admno => @scorecard.admn_no)
else
@results.assign_attributes(:admno => @scorecard.admn_no)
end end
```

here is the error

```js
Result Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "results" WHERE "results"."admno" = ? LIMIT 1  [["admno", 3457]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 123ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `admn_no' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/scorecard.rb:1127:in `export_params'
  app/controllers/scorecards_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

Comment: `@scorecard` is nil in your method. Where are you defining it?

Comment: I do not get you. Where should it be ideally defined at? 
`self.admn_no` is the same as `@scorecard.admn_no` ?
they seem to be working when called to view(no nil) but when persisting them, brings up the error.

Comment: no, it's not the same thing. You aren't defining `@scorecard`, hence it's nil, generating the error.

Comment: I am new to Ruby. I get lost at defining `@scorecard`. since the current model is `@scorecard`. or scribble some rough code on guiding me on this.

Comment: `when Result.where(:admno => self.admn_no).exists?` it's `admn_no` or `admno` in `Result` ?

Comment: in model `scorecard` it's `admn_no` and on `result` it's `admno`
the creation/update in `scorecard` should trigger the same in `result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it :). 
here is how I did it-

```
when Result.where(:admno => self.admn_no).first_or_create do |result|
result.admno=self.admn_no
 end
```

thankyou, your suggestions certainly pointed this the direction it needed

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord associations when using `has_one` or `belongs_to` relationships, use singular version of the model name. For example:

```
belongs_to :result
```

and for `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations use plural version:

```
has_many :scorecards
```

This is the Rails convention. Check out ActiveRecord [associations documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association).

Comment: thank you @Aref I have effected the change; unfortunately; the error is still there :(